# ansible how to add existing host to a group

Tags: ansible

I want to dynamically add an existing host to multiple groups based on a variable defined on the host. Is there a way to do it. I can do group_by, but that only puts it in one group.

eg in my hosts file i have

```
[dc1hosts]
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2

[dc1hosts:vars]
iamDB=True
iamCache=True
<more-properties>

[dc2hosts]
2.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

[dc2hosts:vars]
iamDB=True
<some-more-properties>
```

I want to generate 2 groups called `dbhosts` and `cachehosts` based on who has the `iamDB` flag and who has the `iamCache` flag.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with the [`add_host` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html).

```
- name: Create dynamic groups
  add_host: hostname={{ item }} groups=dbhosts,cachehosts
  with_items: groups['all']
  when:
    - iamDB == True
    - iamCache == True
```

Edit: Probably you meant creating two different groups when any of the conditions is met... but I think you get the picture.

Comment: slight change
    - name: Create dynamic groups
      add_host: hostname={{ item }} groups=dbhosts,cachehosts
      with_items: groups['all']
      when: hostvars[item].iamDB == True

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense! :)

Comment: how can we execute task against the newly created group?

Comment: you can do that with another play in the playbook. in the 1st play you add hosts to a new group, in the 2nd you use that new group